# Resuming the same activity when application restarts

Tags: android, android-activity

I am making an android application related to facts., I want the application to resume where its left when the user restarts the app.
Can anyone help me with that....

Comment: question is not so clear.... Do you mean the "Start up Application".  When device is started or restarted the application will start/open automaticly?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to open an activity which the user was using before the app was quit or destroyed. Though the question isn't much clear, so, I will have to make the above assumption.

You could get the current activity on the every activity the user visits, and store/update the value. In the main activity, launch that activity from `onCreate()`.

Comment: Apologies for the unclear language of question....Thats exactly what i was asking.  Thanks

Comment: How can i find out the activity that the user visits?

Comment: As you can tell by the question i am a beginner..... I would really appreciate if you could guide me through it. I am stuck at this step. Do you have an email id where i could reach you? I would really appreciate it